# Gradle project depends on just one jar from another project

Tags: java, jar, gradle, build

I have a multi-project build in Gradle and my problem is that one of my projects depends on just one jar produced during building another project. To be more clear:
Project A produces: a.jar, b.jar, c.jar, d.jar
Project B depends on: b.jar only

Is there a way to be dependent not on the whole project A but the b.jar only?

Has anybody solved something similar?

Comment: Really not sure but maybe something like this will work: `project.jar.outputs.files.find { it.name == 'b.jar' }` added as a dependency.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible via configurations. Let's say you add *b.jar* to a custom configuration in project A:

```
configurations {
    bArchives
}

artifacts {
    bArchives bJarTask
}
```

where *bJarTask* is the task that creates *b.jar*. Now in project B you can declare a dependency on that custom configuration:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(path: ":a", configuration: "bArchives")
}
```

Unfortunately, there is a catch. This will *only* include *b.jar* in the runtime classpath, not any of *b.jar*'s transitive dependencies. If you want those transitive dependencies added, you should be able to have your custom artifact configuration extend the appropriate dependencies configuration in project A:

```
configurations {
    bArchives.extendsFrom "bRuntime"
}
```

I haven't tested this last bit, so I'm not 100% sure it will work. The Java plugin works differently in that it adds the artifact from the *jar* task directly to the *runtime* configuration.